# Capture screen on iphone as UIImage?

Tags: iphone, screen-capture

I have been reading about how to capture the current screen of the iPhone in code and get it as a UIImage. From what I have understood Apple now allow us to use UIGetScreenImage(void) also when submitting apps to App Store, is that right? Is this the way to go or is there a new better way of capture the screen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

UIGetScreenImage() is not allowed anymore, use AVCaptureDevice instead.

Answer (score 0):

I do not agree with iwat:

UIGetScreenImage() is working. Please follow the [Link](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/screen-capture-using-uigetscreenimage.html).